# I lived Vs. I was living

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

> In 1999, I **was living** in Cuba.
>
> In 1999, I **lived** in Cuba.

Do both sentences seem grammatically correct?

My teacher had told that the first sentence, which is with past continuous, is incorrect. I don't know whether or not the first sentence is correct. It indeed seems natural, doesn't it?

Comment: En 1999, estaba viviendo en Cuba. En 1999, vivi en Cuba. The word is grammatically. You tell your teacher that the choice of verb tense depends on what you are saying.

Comment: off topic, but ESL:  Instead of "Do the both sentence seem grammaticality correct?"  Most people would say either "Do **both** sentence**s** seem grammatical**ly** correct?" or "Do **the two** sentence**s** seem grammatical**ly** correct? "

Comment: If anything there is incorrect, doubtless your teacher will be able to explain how and why.

Either way, that passage would be better as “My teacher said/ has told me that the first sentence, which is in the past continuous, is incorrect. I don't know whether the first sentence is correct. It does seem natural, doesn't it?”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct but the usage depends on the context.

As you noted one is in *past simple tense* while the other in *past continuous tense*, and there is a difference between them in use.

> In 1999, I **lived** in Cuba.

It means that you lived there **not** temporary (permanent).

as opposed to

> In 1999, I **was living** in Cuba.

It means that you lived there temporary (not permanent).

So, maybe your teacher meant to say that it is not correct to use both for the same period of living there.

Sources and further reading:

1. [Cambridge dictionary: She lives Vs. She's living.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present/present-simple-or-present-continuous)
2. [Use 7: Temporary Situations in the Past](https://www.englishtenses.com/tenses/past-continuous#use-7)
3. [Notes/Present_vs_Progressive_vs_Past](http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Present_vs_Progressive_vs_Past.htm)
4. [past-continuous-use.](http://www.focus.olsztyn.pl/en-past-continuous-use.html)
5. [Past Tenses in English](http://www.english-at-home.com/grammar/past-tenses-in-english/).
6. [Temporary and Permanent](http://www.optimatraining.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Past-Continuous.pdf)

Comment: However, I didn't get why she told me that the first sentence is truly wrong.

Comment: Maybe you didn't get her well or maybe she doesn't know or maybe I'm wrong as well as this site and many books that you can see on Google books. It happens to be sometimes that people make mistakes:).

Comment: I showed in my answer two different sources of English teachers that supports my opinion. Could you show please one source that supports your opinion?

Comment: You said that to your mind "lived" is temporary. Do you still hold it in your  mind? https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present/present-simple-or-present-continuous

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75386/discussion-between-gossar-and-archimedean-point).

Comment: To summarize my impressions: Especially since the phrase "In 1999" delimits **both** examples, this answer would be improved if it also addressed concepts other than temporary aspect to distinguish "lived" from "was living".

Comment: "*Kim **worked** in Israel **for one year**" and "**In 2010**,  Kim worked and lived in Jerusalem*." The actions occurred at a specific point in time,  they were temporary in nature because, we infer that Kim's situation changed the following year. But if I said "*Kim **works** and **lives** in Israel*" that expresses the idea of something being either long term or permanent.

Answer (score 3):

Both sentences are grammatically correct but they imply different things.  Because of this, one of them will be the better choice depending on the context.  It is this match between hint and context that makes something feel natural.

> In 1999, I lived in Cuba.

That's a declarative statement. The most important idea you're trying to convey is where you lived in 1999 [full stop].

> In 1999, I was living in Cuba.

This still says where you lived in 1999, but that's no longer the main idea; it hints at something else.   You are either responding to or about to introduce a more important idea and where you lived in 1999 is secondary to that.

For example, that sentence would make sense and sound natural if you're now in Europe and responding to someone else who has been talking about the introduction of the euro.  "In 1999, I was living in Cuba.  I don't really remember that."

Another context where it would make sense and sound natural would be if you went on to talk about watching the Baltimore Orioles play in Havana.  "In 1999, I was living in Cuba.  I can still remember how excited the island was during the exhibition game."  There's more to the story and the first  sentence alone doesn't tell it all.

Now, as to why your teacher called it wrong.  I don't know but here are some guesses.

- It's a common mistake for English language learners to use a "was {verb}ing" construction in all cases, even where the simple past should be used instead (which ends up sounding very unnatural).  Some people over-correct by avoiding this construction even when it might be okay to use.
- This "was {verb}ing" can hide whether or not you know the proper conjugation of an irregular verb.  As a teacher I may be more interested in some other, specific aspect at the moment.  In other words, it may have been the wrong answer for that particular exercise.
- You could be "reading into the question."  When a word choice is justified by context but that context is not given, look to see if there is an alternative that does not need an assumption.  Many questions will ask you to pick the **best** answer.

---

There is a nice [comparison of the past continuous and past simple](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/past/past-continuous-or-past-simple) by *English Grammar Today* at the Oxford Dictionary website.

Comment: Here's a third context, in which the example makes sense but is supernatural. "In 1999, I was living in Cuba" could mean you're about to say that you became a zombie in 2000.

Comment: I've never come across that *hide whether or not you know the proper conjugation of an irregular verb* idea before, but first impressions are it seems quite plausible. I can certainly imagine a learner using *Last night I am having too much to drink* because they forgot/didn't trust the irregular past tense ***had***.  Do you have any references to back it up?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, experience (but I'll look for something more specific).  Maybe "gloss over" would sound less pejorative than "hide"—it's probably not really an intentional deception unless grades are involved.