# Did I use correct tenses in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, tense, past-simple, past-continuous

Regarding my competence in speaking about this topic, I could say that:

> I learned German at school, or I was learning German at School.

> I studied German, or I was studying German.

Comment: Hello Jovana.  What is the particular concern about the tenses here.  I don't like to answer questions that just ask "is this right".  "Yes/No" is not helpful for you.  Why do you have a concern about the tenses here.  Why is this particularly concerning for you.  If you just want it checked for your CV.  Sorry but this isn't a free proofreading service.

Comment: I just wanted to know if I should use was learning and was studying instead of learned and studied, I am not sure which one of these two is more correct.

Comment: I've edited down to just that.  Which do you think is better?

Comment: Related: [I lived Vs. I was living](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/162259/9161)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say either.  Changing the word, or changing the tense will change the meaning.

"Study" is what you do, and "Learn" is the consequence.

If you say "I learned German at school".  That would mean that by the time you finished school you knew German.

> I learned German at school, so it was easy for me to pick up Dutch when I moved to The Netherlands for work.

If you say "I was learning German." I am expecting to hear what interuppted your learning.  It suggests the learning was in progress and incomplete when it ended. Or "I was learning German" could be a reference to what was happening at a certain time in your schooldays.

> I was at school, learning German when the Headteacher came and told us that we all had to assemble in the hall, because the space shuttle had exploded.

If you say I studied that is a simple past tense.  I doesn't always mean you learned anything (I studied Art at school, but learned very little). Again, if you say "I was studying" it sounds as if something interrupted your studies.

Normally you would say "I studied German" since few people could learn everything about a language while at school.

Comment: Or "I was learning/studying German" could be a reference to what was happening at a certain time in your schooldays.